# I cannot get bower through my corporate proxy

Tags: node.js, osx-elcapitan, bower-install

The following is my latest error.  I cannot add more than 2 links to a question so I am cheating, xx = http

```
project mmf3jj$ sudo npm install && bower install

npm WARN package.json UPS_WEM@0.0.1 No license field.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53

                throw err;
                ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/mmf3jj/.config/configstore/update-notifier-bower.json'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
    at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
    at new UpdateNotifier (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:35:17)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:120:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/bin/bower.js:140:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
```

I have done the following:

- verified my proxy exceptions
- recognized git//:

  - sudo git config --global url."xxs://".insteadOf git://
- Allow npm through proxy

  - sudo npm config set proxy xx://username:password@PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT/
  - sudo npm config set https-proxy xx://username:password@PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT/
- double checked my PATH
- configured Bower behind the proxy

  - export proxy xx://username:password@PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT/
  - export https-proxy xx://username:password@PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT/
- edited .bowerrc

.

```
{
    "directory": "library",
    "registry": "xxs://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git/",
    "proxy":"xx://username:password@PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT",
    "https-proxy":"xx://username:password@PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT"
}
```

**UPDATE**

I followed the Apple instructions to turn off the new security setting.  That got npm and everything else to work, but bower is still having the issue.

```
Machintosh: user$ sudo bower install
bower ESUDO         Cannot be run with sudo

Additional error details:
Since bower is a user command, there is no need to execute it with superuser permissions.
If you're having permission errors when using bower without sudo, please spend a few minutes learning more about how your system should work and make any necessary repairs.

http://www.joyent.com/blog/installing-node-and-npm
https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

You can however run a command with sudo using --allow-root option
Machintosh:folder user$ bower install
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53



Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/user/.config/configstore/update-notifier-bower.json'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
    at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
    at new UpdateNotifier (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:35:17)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:120:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/bin/bower.js:140:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

Comment: The source of the problem is my OS.  I am running MAC OS 10.11.xxx, El Capitan. In this OS you can not alter /usr/bin. There is a fix, one is to change that setting, _not recommended_. The other to download the latest version of node.js. This will change the path to usr/local/bin, **recommended**.  I will post an update once I figure out the process to make this update.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in the past and it was caused by the fact that the company proxy was using NTLM authentication. Bower and NPM both presented issues with this proxy and i have to write a cascade proxy to present a more standard authentication method to the client tools.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if is a proxy issue, have you tried to execute both commands as root?, like:

```
sudo su
npm install && bower install
```

Comment: When I tried that this was the response, "su: unknown login: npm".

Comment: first you have to change to root with **sudo su** then hit enter and then type **npm install && bower install**, or you can put sudo to both commands **sudo npm install && sudo bower install**

Comment: Thank you.  Now the system is very clearly telling me that npm / bower cannot get through the proxy.  After rechecking the proxy settings are correct.  Sadly I think yeiniel may be correct.